# Where is the documentation for RSpec.describe?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I can't find it in https://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec or anywhere.

Comment: It doesn't have source code browsing, but the general documentation is here: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-6/docs/example-groups/basic-structure-describe-it

Answer (score 2):

It is defined using `define_method` by `DSL::expose_example_group_alias_globally`
inside [DSL Module](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb).

Better documented in [Class: RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup](https://rspec.info/documentation/3.9/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/ExampleGroup.html)  because return a subclass of `ExampleGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

It is documented, as a ["language"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), in [RSpec Core](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs) with the basics in [basic structure (`describe`/`it`)](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/basic-structure-describe-it).

> The describe method creates an example group. Within the block passed to
> describe you can declare nested groups using the describe or context
> methods, or you can declare examples using the it or specify methods.

> Under the hood, an example group is a class in which the block passed to
> describe or context is evaluated. The blocks passed to it are evaluated
> in the context of an instance of that class.

And as [Giuseppe answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62853523/14660), example groups are documented at the code level in [RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup](https://rspec.info/documentation/3.9/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/ExampleGroup.html).

Comment: That's useful but as it can be called as a class method (like `RSpec.describe`) I expected to find the signature of this method in https://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec, something like `.describe(*args, &block) => ExampleGroup`, with an explanation about `*args`, ex. I've seen in https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/metadata/described-class that the 1st argument can be a class. Explaining that and any other possibilities with those arguments would be clarifying.

Comment: @Xavi It would be nice if they added that. `describe` is dynamically generated alias of `example_group`. There is no rspec.rb. You can find where its generated with `RSpec.method(:describe).source_location` and then `RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup.method(:describe).source_location`. Otherwise, I think you've got it. It takes a name and metadata.